# Problems implementing Growl

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, growl

I am trying to include Growl support in an app, but it is crashing when setting the delegate. As per http://growl.info/documentation/developer/implementing-growl.php , I am just setting the delegate like so `[GrowlApplicationBridge setGrowlDelegate:@""];` as I am only needing Growl for basic usage, but upon running it crashes.

Xcode shows the following warning on that line:

`Semantic Issue: Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSString *' to parameter of type 'NSObject<GrowlApplicationBridgeDelegate> *'`

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Fixed: I set added  to my header file and set the delegate to self

Fixed 2: It actually wasn't that, it was the version of growl sdk I was using having a bug in it, fixed with v1.2.2 of growl.

Comment: An empty string is not the same as a nil object. What makes you think that an empty string constant is a good object to set as the delegate?

Comment: The growl documentation says so.

Comment: That's a good answer :-)! I checked the docs and they mention it's a bug in 1.1. The current version is 1.2.2 so perhaps they fixed it? I can't find a public bug tracker to confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the version of growl sdk I was using having a bug in it, fixed with v1.2.2 of growl.

Answer (score 3):

Don't set the delegate (leave out that line) and you should be fine.

If you need a delegate that you have to set it to an instance of a class that implements the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Cast it to an untyped object to eliminate the warning.

```
 [GrowlApplicationBridge setGrowlDelegate:(id)@""];
```

Comment: That'll cause a run time error when it tries to send a delegate message to a string object.